# Как взять слово, если известны только первые и последние буквы?

Tags: python, текст

Есть огромный список и он всегда рандомный, но в нем есть ссылка:

`words = ['***', 'Primer.net/rsrc.php/pTeXjRdVk8c/page', '***']`

pTeXjRdVk8c - эти символы каждый раз рандомны. И как мне из 'Primer.net/rsrc.php/' и '/page' получить полную ссылку? Надеюсь понятно объяснил.

Comment: Регулярным выражением. Почитайте про них, пригодится.

Comment: `[x for x in words if x.startswith('Primer.net/rsrc.php/') and x.endswith('/page')]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, с помощью *регулярных выражений*:

```
import re

words = ['***', 'Primer.net/rsrc.php/pTeXjRdVk8c/page', '***']
r = re.compile(r'Primer\.net/rsrc\.php/(\w+)/page')
res = list(filter(len, (r.findall(x) for x in words)))
print(res)
```

Вывод:

```
[['pTeXjRdVk8c']]
```